# Custom Ajax request with jQuery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I want to validate a form with the [jQuery form validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) but I was not able to send a custom Ajax request with the validation handler:

```
  $('#headForm').validate(
  {
    //submitHandler: submit,
    errorClass: "invalid",
    rules: {
      title: {maxlength: 50}
    },
    messages: {
      title: {maxlength: 'Max 50 chars'}
    }
  });
```

My orginal submit handler looked like this:

```
  $('#headForm').submit(function(event) 
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/target",
        data: $('#headForm').serialize(),
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function() 
          { 
            alert("ok");
          }
      });
  });
```

I tried to move it to a usual function and register it as a `submitHandler` in the validation block, but it didn't work.

```
  function submit() { // impossible to pass the event!
    $.ajax( ...
  }
```

How can I combine jQuery validation with a custom Ajax request?

**Possible form validation bug:**
I've removed the validation code to see whether the submission works without it. And it did not unless I removed the link to jQuery form validation library! So it seems like validation is breaking jQuery core. Have I already said that I love dynamic typing ... ;-)

Comment: just to clarify, you want to use Ajax to do some of the validation?

Comment: I want to use jQuery for validation and form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define a parameter in the `submit()` function?

(I'm guessing that you didn't, and that could be why it didn't work)

I think you just need to specify the 'form' parameter, and then call `serialize()` on that parameter, as follows:

```
submitHandler: function(form) { 
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/target",
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function() 
      { 
        alert('ok');
      }
    });
   }
```

See the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: The form is submitted with your code, but the success function is not executed!

Comment: so, I can immediately think of 2 reasons for this. 1. Potentially the request didn't 'succeed', so try adding an 'error' handler (similar to the 'success' function definition), or perhaps the validation failed?